# Макросы в WinAPI

Tags: windows, winapi

Почему в WINAPI так много макросов, которые по сути являются одним и тем же?

Вот например `WINAPI` и `CALLBACK` являются по сути одним и тем же, но с разными названиями.

К чему было придумано это буйство типов?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Из тех же самых соображений, почему мы придумываем разные имена переменных, а не используем i1, i2, i3... для целых и b1, b2, b3... для булевых. Имя типа, переменной, класса, и т.д. должно отражать его назначение и давать максимум информации о его использовании. Префикс `WINAPI` говорит о том, что функция является частью Windows API, и подчиняется его соглашению о вызове (calling convention). `CALLBACK` говорит о том, что это пользовательская функция, вызываемая какой-то функцией WinAPI. Тот факт, что где-то в дебрях windef.h они обе определены как `__stdcall`, не более чем совпадение, которое программиста вообще интересовать не должно. И кстати, что касается именно этих определений, то совпадают они не для всех платформ.

Еще одна цель определений WinAPI - независимость от платформы. Если я объявляю переменную как `DWORD`, мне неважно, что именно в моей системе она будет объявлена как `unsigned long`. Достаточно знать, что она будет четырехбайтовой на любой платформе, даже там, где long имеет длину 64 бита.